# How to correctly extract python command line args into strings

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have following python script which wants to intake the first argument as a string, reverse it and then print it out

```
import sys

input = sys.argv[1:]
input_reversed = input[::-1]
print("The input_reversed is: " + input_reversed)
```

Running it with a call like `python test.py abcdef` gets me the following error which says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print("The input_reversed is: " + input_reversed)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

What am I dong wrong? `sys.argv[1:]` does not return a string?

**I just want to** call `python test.py abcdef` and get the output as `fedcba` which is a reverse of `abcdef`.

Comment: `['one', 'two', 'three'][1:]` is `['two', 'three']` -- that's a list of strings, not a string.

Comment: I just want to call `python test.py abcdef` and get the output as `fedcba`

Comment: Ahh! That's not what your code does; it reverses the order of the arguments, it doesn't reverse the individual arguments' text. (So if you pass only one argument, that list can't meaningfully be reversed at all, so it stays the same).

Comment: Assuming only one argument and ```len``` > 1, you can use ```sys.argv[1][::-1]``` and save that as a variable.

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` gets the first argument in a string and thats what I wanted to do here. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the content of each argument to be reversed, *in addition to* reversing the order of the arguments themselves, join all your arguments together into a string and then reverse that string:

```
print("The reversed input is: " + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])[::-1])
```

Notice the order of operations here. It could be written with more intermediate steps as:

```
args_list = sys.argv[1:]
args_string = ' '.join(args_list)
reversed_args_string = args_string[::-1]
print("The reversed input is: " + reversed_args_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it returns a list. You can join a list together using `join()`. Try this:

```py
print("The input_reversed is: " + ', '.join(input_reversed))
```

Comment: Doing the `join` causes the output to be not reversed but stay the same? This is interesting. Can you please check the output of this join? The reverse is reversed.

Comment: Eh? `', '.join(['one', 'two', 'three'][::-1])` is propertly `'three, two, one'` -- the reverse holds.

Comment: It will just join the items of the list together using whatever delimiter you define. The output will be in the same order as the list you pass to the function. So if you use ', `.join(['a','b','c'])` you'll get the result `"a, b, c"`